# Both USB & Ethernet NOK on brand new Pi 3 Model V v1.2

Tags: usb, pi-3, ethernet-port

I have a brand new Pi 3 Model V v1.2, using raspbian, with both USB and Ethernet completely dead - keyboard and network don't work.  The same keyboard and network work on an older Pi 1 next to it.

On boot it shows a few lines of "Raspberry Pi  dwc otg handle mode mismatch intr 68 mode mismatch interrupt currently in device mode".  Could this be the same problem described on https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=98&t=87123 ?  How would I "ground the OTG pin" on a Pi 3 (and is this a good idea) ?

Or is this hopeless, clear hardware fault - buy another one? I just got this one! ;-)

FYI It initially gave the "rainbow box" on boot (not the little rainbow in the upper right hand corner), so I bought a new power. Even with this strong power, it works once and on reboot still gives the "rainbow box" on re-boot - too hot? Bad SD card which works once and then on reboot is too hot?!  From what I understand, this is technically a separate problem from my main problem described above, because when it does boot, then there is a blinking cursor, and apart from no working kbd and nw I think it's fine & happy.

PS: I've run rpi-update and apt-get update/ upgrade on the micro SD card inserted into an older Pi 1, to have latest software on the card.

Comment: If it is a power issue I think they could be related; note the ethernet and USB use the same controller.  The big rainbow on boot though isn't power though, it just means it did not boot beyond a certain point and is stuck there (that screen always appears briefly, I think).  A dud or missing SD card might do that.  If you have a spare card I would try burning the most recent Raspbian onto it and see what happens.

Comment: Did you download the new OS for Pi3? The old OS's wont work on the new Pi3.

Comment: I DL from here https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/, that should work for the Pi3, right

Comment: FTR I've tried this with another SD card and still same error. So I much suspect that this board has a hardware fault, and will try to get another one.

Answer (score 1):

FTR: This message (`"Raspberry Pi dwc otg handle mode mismatch intr 68 mode mismatch interrupt currently in device mode"`) appears to indicate a (brand new!) RPi 3 broken at the hardware level... I just got another new one, and with the SAME SD card(s) and USB keyboard and Ethernet network cable the new one works great.